# CSS float is not working

Tags: html, css

After thoroughly researching for the way to fix this I have still not found the answer I seek. I finally decide to post my problem on stackoverflow.com because I finally give up trying to find the answer. What I get as a result is two boxes with content on top and one box on the bottom.
Here is the CSS code:

```
#content_area
{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 110px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div>
<div class="box">
//enter text here
</div>
<div class="box">
//enter text here
</div>
<div class="box">
//enter text here
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for not putting any pressure on us. ;) Please consider improving your question by describing the expected and actual behaviors you're seeing with the posted code.

Comment: remove `display:inline-block`

Comment: Where should I remove it from?

Comment: padding for `.box` prevented blocks to be in one line. As a suggestion, do not use floats. You can use `display: table` for parent block and `dispay: table-cell` for inside blocks. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nu2nLzvq/)

Comment: How does `#content_area` apply to your question?

Comment: #content_area is the div where the boxes go.

Comment: from the box, but as @lolbas suggested you can just remove `float:left`. inline-block will give you the same thing you're looking for

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: `width:33.33%` and `padding:15px` makes the element's total width `33.33% + 15px`. This of course extends it above 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your padding, as mentioned above.

Here is a fiddle with the padding removed and colours added: http://jsfiddle.net/gj0wmgym

```
.box
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I sort of want the padding, is that a problem?

Comment: Actually, I got it! Thanks SOO much!

Comment: @ErikEllasandre I usually just add an inner div to solve that problem.

Another option is do:

`width: calc(33.33% - 10px)`

Where 10px is your padding size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your `.box` class assigns a width of 33%, with additional padding. This leads to a total width of more than 100%. Padding is added to the `.box`'s initial width because that's how the default box model works in CSS.

To fix this problem, add this line to the `.box`'s style declarations:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

You can see a live demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYbaQj). If you want to learn more about the box model, [this article by Chris Coyier is an excellent reference.](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

Comment: Any reason you use codepen over JSFiddle? Just curious.

Comment: @caleb.breckon It's less laggy in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your floats are working correctly.

Your html was missing the id attribute, so make sure to add that to your html.

What you are probably expecting is for the floats to not wrap to the next line, which is because the padding gets added to the width size (the elements are greater than 33%). You instead need to set the box sizing attribute [see this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#content_area
{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 110px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_area">
<div class="box">
//enter text here
</div>
<div class="box">
//enter text here
</div>
<div class="box">
//enter text here
</div>
</div>
```